# Change Default Service Version of Microsoft Azure Blob - PHP

Tags: php, azure, azure-blob-storage

```
$this->blobClient = ServicesBuilder::getInstance()
                                ->createBlobService($azureString);

$properties = $this->blobClient->getServiceProperties();
```

How can i change the default service version of microsoft azure?

Currently it is set at 2009-09-19. i want to change it to 2012-02-12.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean [`STORAGE_API_LATEST_VERSION`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-php/blob/f41e074cd0359d56e10352ba553fbb37ce4ff0bd/src/Common/Internal/Middlewares/CommonRequestMiddleware.php#L67)? It is set to [**2015-04-05**](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-php/blob/master/src/Common/Internal/Resources.php#L259)
 in the latest SDK version ([v 0.14.0](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-php/releases/tag/v0.14.0)).

However, you can change it at:

```
vendor\microsoft\azure-storage\src\Common\Internal\Resources.php
```

---

### EDIT:

Per [Azure's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/versioning-for-the-azure-storage-services#specifying-storage-service-versions-in-requests),

> If a request to the Blob service does not specify the `x-ms-version` header, and the default version for the service has not been set using [Set Blob Service Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/set-blob-service-properties), then the earliest version of the Blob service is used to process the request. However, if the container was made public with a [Set Container ACL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/set-container-acl) operation performed using version 2009-09-19 or newer, then the request is processed using version 2009-09-19.

So you can specify the `x-ms-version` header to change **DefaultServiceVersion** via Postman.

[image]

Comment: Hi. Mr. Aarron. Thanks for the reply. It is set to 2015-04-05. however when i access the audio using postman. **x-ms-version** is 2009-09-19. is there any way to change DefaultServiceVersion. I think azure uses the oldest one which is 2009-09-19

Answer (score 9):

To expand on Aaron Chen's answer, you can actually [set the default service version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/set-blob-service-properties) permanently, so that you don't have to provide the *x-ms-version* request header to get newer features for public requests (like "*Accept-Ranges: bytes*" header for example). It is a bit of a hassle though, because almost no SDK actually supports setting this property. What worked for me is to use the following PowerShell code. It's **for Windows only** (the DotNetCore-Azure modules for other platforms do not support that either), but it works using the *Cloud Shell* within Azure Portal if you don't have access to a Windows environment.

Within *Cloud Shell*:

```
PS Azure:\> $ctx = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName <account-name> -StorageAccountKey <key>
Azure:\
PS Azure:\> Update-AzureStorageServiceProperty -ServiceType Blob -DefaultServiceVersion 2017-07-29 -Context $ctx
```

This will set the default version of the storage account's service to *2017-07-29* (the newest at the time of this writing) for all requests which don't provide their own x-ms-version header. See this [list for an overview of the different versions available](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/versioning-for-the-azure-storage-services).

Within a Windows PowerShell environment you have to install the Azure modules as well:

As an admin:

```
Install-Module -Name AzureRM -AllowClobber
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
```

As a user

```
Import-Module Azure.Storage
$ctx = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName <account-name> -StorageAccountKey <key>
Update-AzureStorageServiceProperty -ServiceType Blob -DefaultServiceVersion 2017-07-29 -Context $ctx
```

Comment: I was able to do it with the Python SDK, but the name for the setting was `target_version`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I use this [list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/previous-azure-storage-service-versions) to check the version. Works very well.