# Multipart byteranges on Azure static website

Tags: azure, http, webserver

As it seems, Azure now has an option to publicly serve the contents of Blob storage via HTTP, mainly intended for [static websites](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-storage-static-web-hosting-public-preview/). It is rather new and currently tagged as "preview".

I'd like to store binary releases (about 3 GB each version) of a game on Azure storage, and allow players to perform a differential update to any version using a [zsync](http://zsync.moria.org.uk/)-like algorithm. For this way to work, it is crucial to be able to downloaded only specified chunks of a large file. Normally, this is achieved over HTTP by sending a [multipart byteranges GET request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Range_requests#Multipart_ranges).

The question is: is it possible to enable HTTP requests with multiple byteranges on the Azure "static website"?

**UPDATE**: As Itay Podhajcer mentioned, I don't need the "static website" feature for serving my blob storage over HTTP, I can directly open my storage container for public. However, multipart byteranges requests do **not** work with direct access to blob storage too.

Answer (score 1):

The **Azure Static Website** service is intended more for **Single Page Applications** (such as **Angular** and **React** apps).

If you only need to store binary content to be downloaded by clients, I think you should be fine using the "regular" **Blob** container.
To specify the a range header on a GET request, you can follow [Specifying the Range Header for Blob Service Operations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/specifying-the-range-header-for-blob-service-operations).

Hope it helps!

Comment: Do I understand you right that I can serve contents of Blob storage on a public HTTP address, and I don't even need "static website" thing? This is very strange. In fact, I cannot see any difference between serving static html+js+jpg+mp3 for browsers and serving binary content for downloading.

Comment: The static website has out-of-box support for relevant mime types (because you don't want to trigger a download when a user access your SPA and additionally, it should have the functionality to handle routes correctly. You should be able to set the container as a accessible from the internet (either at the content level or even the entire container level).

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get multipart byteranges working by using CDN.
The full list of actions is:

1. Screw "static website" feature: as Itay Podhajcer wrote, it is absolutely unnecessary.
2. Upgrade DefaultServiceVersion using Cloud Shell, as said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49286412/556899) (to ensure that Accept-Ranges is included in HTTP headers).
3. Enable "Standard Akamai" CDN to serve Blob Storage directly.

After that I can send multipart byteranges requests to the CDN endpoint, and it gives back multipart response with exactly the data I requested.